# how to show same image in all view without implementing it in all view?

Tags: iphone

I want to show my apps logo image in top of every view. But I want to create it once in a view that show it in every view like master page in ASP.net. please some one help me.

Comment: I don't know `master page in ASP.net`. To give more readers a chance to answer your question you should add some explanation what exactly you want. Do you want some kind of overlay which is somewhere above others or do you want it to be in the navigation bar?

Comment: in a website there is some image which we can see in every page of that website. I want such thing in iphone but not in navigation bar.

Comment: do you want have something underneath the image or will it be only the image at the top of every view?

Comment: Sandy use Olivers ans...because you can never use single imageview for multiple use. Each and every time you need to create it and add to current displayed view. You have another option to create single view and add separate UIViewController, where only separate view controller can move back and forth but base view remains fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Create a subclass of UIViewController, and in viewDidLoad method, get and place the image where your want :

.h

```
@interface MyLogoViewController : UIViewController
// your interface
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MyLogoViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame.origin.x = // whatever you want
    imageView.frame.origin.y = // whatever you want
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}

@end
```

Then for any of your view controller that controls a view in wich you want that image to be displayed should inherit that subclassed View controller instead of UIViewController.

```
@interface MyNewViewController : MyLogoViewController {
// your interface
}

@end
```

That way, image displays automatically without having to do anything special.

If you plan to add subviews programmatically in your view controllers, then keep a reference for `imageView` into `MyLogoViewController` class as a member var (instead of just creating / releasing it on the fly), so you will be able to put your new views behind the existing logo if needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can place that image in main.window. so you can see that image in every view which views are having subviews to main window. But you need fix all view sizes according to your images size fixed in main window.Thats enough.

Comment: yah I want this one process but I could not do it. plz explain it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the image to window and have fix the size of the view then u can see in sub view

Answer (score 1):

YOu can add that view in window and add other view below that window image. so you can see that in every page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a modal class for the image and call this from viewDidLoad of every controller.

Comment: is there any way that it will comes like when we create a tabbar in main windows it show in every page??

Comment: if using navigation bar then u can call the draw rect method and assign the image to it. If not then u can have a class method where u will set the image and return the image object from wherever u call this method.